# What are some words I could use to call someone who is not good at work?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I asked this question because the other question on [workplace.se](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31922/should-i-talk-to-my-enemy). I realized that "enemy" is not the right word to express my idea.

I was working with that person for about a year. He was bad at work and never followed the rules or standards. I didn't like him because of his performance, not because of his personality.

What are some words I could use to call him?

Comment: Like slacker?...

Comment: Do not call him anything. It is not for us to judge others, especially at the workplace. You should not have "didn't like him because of his performance," which is improper. This is an etiquette/workplace related issue, though. If you still want to know the word you are looking for, post an appropriate impersonal question here.

Comment: @Kris, I told the story to clarify the question. Without context, it might be misleading. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could label this person as being ***an incompetent colleague***. *[Incompetent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incompetent)* expresses the concept that an employee is unable, for whatever reason, to perform or carry out his or her duties at work to the best of their ability. It is a formal and common expression, easily understood by all.

> People were shocked that he allowed some of his incompetent  workers
>   to stay on after a mistake.

<sup>Source: Dictionary.com</sup>
If you prefer a more informal expression you could talk about your co-worker's *shoddy work*, or *[shoddy workmanship](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoddy)*, which implies the employee took short-cuts, used inferior quality materials, and generally had a lax attitude concerning projects, tasks, meeting deadlines etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think [unprofessional](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Unprofessional)   may describe the employee attitude you are referring to:

> - not characteristic of or befitting a profession or one engaged in a profession;  " unprofessional conduct"; "unprofessional repairs"

Also a [shirker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Shirker),  ( as a more informal definition)

> - a person who evades work, duty, responsibility, etc.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

Words like *shirker* and *slacker* do not have currency in modern management thinking since they are too moralistic. And the purpose of management is not to make judgments about people. It is to fit round pegs in round holes and square ones in square ones.

Nowadays a professional manager might say something to the effect that the individual concerned was not *motivated* to succeed in his present role and circumstances.

Often a person who has not appeared motivated in one particular job, location, or with one particular supervisor, has performed quite differently if moved.

That is not to say that there are not some people who are very difficult to place.